# Onclick event not working when creating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick, createelement

I was adding elements with this code and the onclick event was working fine:

```
$("#main").before('<ul class=\"breadcrumb\"><li><a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"Search(\'' + "/" + '\')\"><span>Home</span></a></li></ul>');
```

But I'm not using jQuery anymore, and with the code below, the onclick events are not firing.
Any idea why this is happening?

```
var breadcrumb = document.createElement('ul');
breadcrumb.className = 'breadcrumb';

var element = document.createElement('li');

var elementlink = document.createElement('a');
elementlink.onclick = function () { 
    Search("/"); 
    return false;
};

var elementspan = document.createElement('span');
elementspan.innerHTML = 'Home';

elementlink.appendChild(elementspan);
element.appendChild(elementlink);
breadcrumb.appendChild(element);

document.getElementById('main').insertBefore(breadcrumb, null);
```

Comment: not firing..the element is showing up fine. I tried to use alert() instead of my function just in case, but it's firing too

Comment: can you specify if solution needs to be in pure js or jquery please.

Comment: I'm not using jquery anymore

Comment: @nhenrique http://jsfiddle.net/mF3KZ/ ???

Comment: this is weird..it's still not working for me

Comment: works for me, and my fiddle down below shows it is possible... never knew, always thought you needed to use listeners...

Answer (score 3):

Add a listener instead of setting the onclick property of the element.

Apparently it should work though: http://jsfiddle.net/6gb2k/

Try:

```
elementlink.addEventListener('onclick', function(e) { ... }, false);
```

or cleaner:

```
var handleClick = function(e) {
    ...
}
elementlink.addEventListener('onclick', handleClick, false);
```

Your above code should work however according to @crush's comment and my fiddle.

Comment: You can, [**in fact**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xb7Cf/), set the `onclick` property directly. It is certainly better practice to use `addEventListener` though since you don't know what other click events might be bound to the object.

Comment: Thanks @crush I changed the answer, please remove your downvote.

Comment: @crush your fiddle doesn't seem to work for me Chrome 31

Comment: this should the right answer..and what's weird it that I'm doing this kind of stuff with onclick events in all my code. Just here, it's not working..and this is the only code running in this function

Comment: I think you'll run into cross browser issues unless you're setting listeners... it's the proper and accepted way to do it. That's opinion though...